# Very high memory usage on Windows 10 but programs don't add up

Tags: windows-10, firefox, memory, performance, memory-management

I generally get a memory usage >80% but when I check the Task Manager, none of the programs add up to that usage. The laptop (Dell XPS 13 9360) frequently has to resort to my SSD with a large number of hard faults shown in the Resource Monitor. I think screenshots speak better to this matter:

[image: Resource Monitor]

[image: RamMap 1]

[image]

Comment: Windows starts paging at about 50% RAM usage, so avoiding it with only 8GB RAM is probably not possible.

Comment: @Tetsujin even if it's impossible to avoid, it would probably still be good to solve this disproportionate memory usage. All my applications use no more than ~2.2GB but 7GB of my memory are somehow used.

Comment: Used memory is not handed back until it is needed again. Free memory == wasted memory. Don't worry about it, it's all in hand.

Comment: I am aware of that. That is why I included the RamMap screenshots. AFAIK the yellow is actually used memory and not e.g. pre-loaded apps. The problem is that my whole computer hangs for easily ~30s when I close a larger application and has frequent shorter (~0.5s) freezes. I assume these are related to memory usage as the CPU usage is normally not that high.

Comment: You only have 8GB. That's not really enough this day & age. The OS will want 3, any browser with a few tabs open will eat another 3 easily, even a pure text page these days will be 150MB. You're already paging at that, so every time you swap another app to the front it has to page back out; that will be the source of your freezes. Either get at least twice as much RAM or stop running your browser at the same time as anything else.

Comment: I am well aware of that but thank you. Unfortunately my Dell XPS 13 (9360) is not upgradeable and this also doesn't explain the discrepancy.

Comment: 8GB is pleeeeenty! I run Chrome with 20 open tabs, VMware Virtiual machines, Visual studio, PhotoShop, Autocad 3D. Not all at once, but many times several. I never have memory issues with my 8GB. I think you have another problem.If you end up against the wall, reinstall Windows and be careful what you install of drivers and apps that might screw your installation.